# They shouldn't be/mustn't be here

Tags: modal-verbs, semi-modals

This sentence is from Michael Vince's  *English* *Grammar* *in* *Context*.

"These books are on the wrong shelf. They shouldn't/mustn't be here."

The exercise asks to choose the right answer. Aren't both correct?

Comment: It's a bad example. The vast majority of native speakers would use ***shouldn't*** in the cited context, but that doesn't mean ***mustn't*** is somehow syntactically or semantically invalid. But since it's presented as an *exercise* in your book, I feel sure the writer must have given some earlier guidance as to the choice ***he expects you to make*** (and an explanation of ***why***, which would probably focus on the fact that ***should*** is less "extreme, obligatory" than ***must***).

Comment: It's hard to imagine a scenario in which certain books _must not_ be on a particular shelf; it implies that they would commit an offence by being there!

Comment: Grammatically, yes, both are correct. However, *shouldn't* is the more frequently-used word for this scenario.